# question in subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

A simple question confuses me a lot.

Q1
  $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^3 : 2x_1+3x_2^3-4x_3^2=0\}$. Show that is not a subspace of  $\mathbb R^3$ .

To show whether $S$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ or not, we set $u,v\in S$.

$u=2u_1+3u_2^3-4u_3^2, v=2v_1+3v_2^3-4v_3^2$, and then follow the processes.

Q2 
  Let P denote the set of all real polynomials of degree less than or equal to 2.
     $S= {P \in P(R): P(x)=ax^2+bx+c}

To show that, we set $u=a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1$ and $v=a_2x^2+b_2x+c_2$

Here is the question.. In Q1 we change the variable x into u and v. But in Q2 why we change the coefficients a,b,c into a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2 instead of changing the variable x???????

Comment: Something seems off with the definition of $S$. It doesn't have a condition, since "$2x+3x^3-4x^2$" is meaningless without $\ge something$ or $= something$ or something similar. Also, how do you define power of a vector? Or should $x^{(k)}$ actually be $x_k$?

Comment: I inferred from the question that it was $x = 2x + 3x^3 - 4x^2$ and edited accordingly.

Comment: I approved it for readability, but it's still meaningless, so I'd rather hear from the OP about that and about powers/indices.

Comment: I have edited the question..is that really something wrong with the definition??

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I still have trouble understanding the definition of $S$. If $x$ is a vector, and $x_k$ are its components (i.e., real numbers), then $x = 2x_1 + 3x_2^3 - 4x_3^2$ is meaningless.

Comment: i correct the question again..

Answer (score 1):

For Q1, take

$$x = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

It is easy to see that $x \in S$. But what about, say, $2x$?

As for Q2, vector is defined by its components $x_1,x_2,x_3$, but a polynomial $p$ is defined by its factors $a,b,c$ and $x$ is merely a variable for which we can get a value of a polynomial. So, $p$ is a polynomial, and $p(x)$ is a real number (once you provide a value for $x$).

Comment: thank you very much..i know what i get wrong...

Answer (score 0):

$v = ( \frac{1}{2},1,1)$ is a element of your space. So you would expect $2v$ to be an element of your space.

Is it?

Comment: i have corrected the question..sorry about that